# Comments in fortran argument list when using doxygen

Tags: fortran, doxygen

I try to generate a doxygen documentation of an existing fortran code. My focus is on generating the call/caller graphs and the function/subroutine signature.

The code (fixed form) contains subroutine definitions like this:

```
       subroutine mysub(var1,
c comment..
     >                  var2,
c comment..
c comment..
     >                  var3,
     >                       )
```

In the genenrated html by doxygen, the subroutine is shown to have only the var1 argument, the others are omitted.

[image]

I use  `OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = YES` and set the correct extension mapping. The only solution I found is to use an `INPUT_FILTER = sed -e '/\(^\s*$\|^[cC*]\)/d'` which just removes all comments and blank lines. This is problematic as the comments are then missing in the linked source file.

To be clear, I don't want to include the above 3 comments in the doxygen output, I just want to preserve the correct method signature.

Comment: Currently the comment inside the argument list is not (yet) supported.